# Ternary Operator dart flutter null. type 'Null' is not a 'bool' in boolean expression

Tags: flutter, dart

i have problem in this code can someone help me.

WorldTime.dart

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class WorldTime {
  String? time;
  String? url;
  String? location;
  String? flag;
  late bool isDaytime;

  WorldTime({this.url, this.location, this.flag});

  Future<void> getTime() async {
    try {
      // make the request
      Response response = await get(Uri.parse('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/$url'));
      Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);

      // get properties from data
      String datetime = data['datetime'];
      String offset = data['utc_offset'].substring(1,3);
  
      // create datetime object
      DateTime now = DateTime.parse(datetime);
      now = now.add(Duration(hours: int.parse(offset))); 
  
      // set the time property
      isDaytime = now.hour > 6 && now.hour < 20 ? true : false;
      time = DateFormat.jm().format(now);

    } catch (e) {
      print('caught error: $e');
      time = 'Cant get datetime';
    }
  }
}
```

loading.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
import 'package:test_worldtime/service/world_time.dart';

class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
}

class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {

  void setWorldTime() async {
    WorldTime instance = WorldTime(url: 'Asia/Jakarta', location: 'Jakarta', flag: 'indonesia.jpg');
    await instance.getTime();
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home', arguments: {
      'location': instance.location,
      'time': instance.time,
      'flag': instance.flag,
      'isDaytime': instance.isDaytime
    });
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setWorldTime();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue[900],
      body: Center(
        child: SpinKitCircle(
          color: Colors.white,
          size: 80.0,
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

home.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:legacy_buttons/legacy_buttons.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  Map data = {};
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    data = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map;
    print(data);

    // set background
    String bgImage = data['IsDayTime'] ? 'day.png' : 'night.png';

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('assets/day.png'),
              fit: BoxFit.cover
            )
          ),
        )
      )
    )
  }
}
```

My problem is when I start run flutter throw some error it say: "type 'Null' is not a 'bool' in boolean expression". I try to put `late` or `bool?` in isDaytime still not work, can someone help me

Edit: This code will error if I uncomment `String bgImage` and change `AssetImage('assets/day.png')` to `AssetImage('assets/$bgImage')`

This link video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NDulhXVcLuI&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9jLYyp2Aoh6hcWuxFDX6PBJ&index=33

Comment: what if instead of marking it as late you mark it as nullable? like: bool? isDaytime

Comment: i try to put `bool?` still not work for me

Comment: Are you positive that the error is from that line?  There is nothing in your ternary condition that could cause it be null.  Also, that ternary expression is useless.  Just do `isDaytime = now.hour > 6 && now.hour < 20;`.

Comment: are you getting null as datetime?

Comment: @jamesdlin I edit my question can you check my question again thanks

Comment: `data['IsDayTime']` will return `null` if the key is not found.  You need to provide a fallback value for that case.  For example: `(data['IsDayTime'] ?? true) ? 'day.png' : 'night.png'`

Comment: My bad guys, all error in this code just because i wrote wrong `String bgImage = data['IsDayTime'] ? 'day.png' : 'night.png';`  `data['isDaytime']`, and that why flutter throw null sorry guys my bed. @jamesdlin thanks for help all

Answer (score 0):

The problem is as said "type 'Null' is not a 'bool' in boolean expression".

This is because:

```
String bgImage = data['IsDayTime'] ? 'day.png' : 'night.png';
```

returns null if the key IsDayTime is not within data.

You can get the desired result and return a bool by using the .containsKey method for Map:

```
String bgImage = data.containsKey('IsDayTime') ? 'day.png' : 'night.png';
```

You can break down the ternary logic to an if-statement to understand it better:

```
if (data.containsKey('IsDayTime')){
  bgImage = 'day.png';
} else {
  bgImage = 'night.png';
}
```

If you wanted to do that but keep the same single line format you already had, you can create a function and assign it's result to the variable:

```
String isDayTime(Map data){
if (data.containsKey('IsDayTime')){
  return 'day.png';
} else {
  return 'night.png';
}
}

String bgImage = isDayTime(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad guys, all error in this code just because i wrote wrong:
`String bgImage = data['IsDayTime'] ? 'day.png' : 'night.png';`

I should have written:
`data['isDaytime']`
because in class WorldTime i put `late bool isDaytime;`,
I mistyped the uppercase and lowercase letters and that why flutter throw null.